# Voting SQL conundrum

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a PHP system that allows users to vote photos on a scale of 1 - 5, what I want to do is highlight where two people give each other the same vote/score. I can't figure the SQL out at the moment for my PHP function.

The database looks like this

```
id, user_uid, voted_uid, score
```

As someone votes the id is auto incremental, the user_id is inserted from the session uid and the voted_uid comes from the image the user is viewing, then the score is the ranking from 1-5.

In theory we are therefore looking for two similar rows like this:

```
uid      user_uid      voted_uid     score
7         3              5            3
38        5              3            3
```

At this point I want my php function to take the current users session and then match their votes and scores with other users.

In the example above I'd have the session id of 3 and I want it to return these two records as matches.

Comment: Can we see your (partial) attempt? That will help guide answers and give readers confidence they've understood the problem correctly.

Comment: What does "session id of 3" mean?

Comment: When a user logs in to this site they get assigned a unique user ID and this is assigned to a session e.g. 3 in this case..

Comment: Earlier I did a sub query to get the results back but that is when I didn't think about the fact I wouldn't have the other users Id just the one logged in so I had something like.   Select * from voting where ((uid =3 and voter_uid =5) or (uid=5 and voter_uid=3)) and score ='3'

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, what you want is to find pairs of rows where `user_uid` of the first row equals `voted_uid` in the second row and vice versa. But only, if `score` is the same in both rows.

In that case, this should do the trick:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM table AS a
JOIN table AS b
  ON a.user_uid  = b.voted_uid
 AND a.voted_uid = b.user_uid
 AND a.score     = b.score;
```

If you only want rows that "mention" a specific uid, you of course have to add a `WHERE user_uid = 3 OR voted_uid = 3`.

Comment: But all the information is witinh the same table, you can't join a table to itself can you?

Comment: @user1573686, yes, you can join a table to itself. That's the purpose of the aliasing via `AS` - they effectively act as different tables.